# DataTable - foreach Row, EXCEPT FIRST ONE

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, iteration, datarow

I am using a `DataTable` for some calculations in my app. I need to do the iterate trough all the rows except the first one. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
DataTable dt;

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows /*EXCEPT THE FIRST ONE*/)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok you got your answers but in case you donT want to use linq. Check the index of the row in the table:

```
            foreach (DataRow row in m_dtMatrix.Rows)
            {
                if (m_dtMatrix.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Comment: also you should be careful cos I think the "first" row depends on the sorting definition of your datatable.

Comment: in the end decided not to go with LINQ, so I used your answer. Thank you all for responses.

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer (and a valid one), checking for every row not being the first isn't ideal, @Adi 's skipping of the first row is a more concise, clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 32):

LINQ is your friend:

```
DataTable dt;
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
{
    //do something...
}
```

The call to `Cast()` is required here since `DataTable.Rows` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, and linq's extension methods are only available for `IEnumerable<T>`

You also have another option:

```
DataTable dt;
foreach (DataRow r in dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(1))
{
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: oh, just one thing...should there not be .Skip(0)?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, since `Skip` takes the number of items to ignore.

Comment: What am I missing - I don't see a Skip method in DataTable.Rows.

Comment: @JayRiggs I just noticed `DataTable.Rows` returns a non-generic `IEnumerable`, so in order to use LINQ, a call to `Cast()` is required. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty

```
DataTable dt;

bool isFirst = true;

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows /*EXCEPT THE FIRST ONE*/)
{
    if( isFirst ) {
        isFirst = false;
        continue;
    }
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: Damn Lester, now I look like a noob.

Comment: I've been doing this for years and never even noticed the Skip() method. Don't even feel bad. :)