# Remove the first column from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Datatable to get some values from a database table.

```
DataTable dt = this.GetData();
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
html.Append("<table border = '1'>");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }
        html.Append("</table>");
```

The above code gives me this output:
[image]
The column with 0 0 is generated from the ID column of my table. I didn't pass the ID through my Stored Procedure because I dont need to display them. Is there a way to remove the first column itself and prevent it from displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use FOR instead of FOREACH and start from 1 instead of 0

```
for(int i=1;i<dt.Columns.Count;i++){//do whatever}
```

Comment: i used this and now im getting error at line html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);.how do I solve this? @Shannon

Comment: ok got it. made this teeny-tiny change further 
"html.Append(row[i]); "

Comment: Yes - when you switch from enumeration to index, you always need to provide the index value. It's ALWAYS row[I]. Sorry I didn't see this earlier and glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Just use Linq [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns.AsEnumerable().Skip(1))
```

Prob best to check that there are enough columns too:

```
if (dt.Columns.Length > 1)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns.AsEnumerable().Skip(1))
    ...etc
```

Comment: tried this and added System.Linq namespace too but it says 'DataColumnCollection' doesn not contain a definition for Skip. How do I solve this please

Comment: use .asenumerable

Comment: Yeah, you need to case as an IEnumerable. Updated

Comment: I'm not sure if its count() or length BTW to test for number of columns. Been a while since I've used a DataTable object. It'll be one or the other. I think it's Length on none IEnumerable objects

Comment: Added AsEnumerable but its giving me error on "dt.Columns". I am beginning to suspect that I am getting all these errors because I got my data as List and used a function to convert them to datatable. I will try and display my data as list itself

Answer (score 0):

```
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

Just remove the column at the specified position.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852925/6156592).

Credit for: [Zortkun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494659/zortkun).

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    if (dt.Columns.IndexOf(column) != 0)
    {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
        html.Append("</td>");
     }
  }
```

It worked for me.